# Does formatting the HDFS filesystem remove my data?

Tags: format, hadoop

I'm starting to learn Hadoop. If I want to format the HDFS filesystem I need to execute

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Does it mean that it will format my filesystem, losing everything I have there?
Or will it just create a kind of big "virtual file" over the local filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

it'll format the HDFS so that you can use it. No harm will be done to your local filesystem.

Comment: Hi. Where could I find more details?

Comment: with regard to format - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/commands_manual.html. The book Hadoop - the definite guide is a must read!